# Replacing escape characters with a space

Tags: java, replace, space

I have been asked to replace a escape characters in a string with a space.

I have been trying like below

```
String replace(String data)
    {
        String strSpecial = "";
        strSpecial = " \f\n\r\t\'\"\\";     

        char charArray[] = strSpecial.toCharArray();
        String strOutData = data;
        for (int i =0;i<charArray.length;i++)
        {  
              strOutData = strOutData.replace(charArray[i], ' ');
    }       
        return(strOutData);

    }
```

Im getting the error - "Unterminated String Constant"

It is working when I use any character instead of a space to replace the escape character.

Please suggest

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: Note: Java != Javascript.

Comment: Yeah, you are right.. but how to achieve that.. is it something like impossible ! ?

Comment: I get no error... Could you provide the input string that makes this error get thrown?

Comment: It sounds like this piece of code is inside a JSP. Am I correct in assuming?

Comment: Try using the string with spaces.. something like "Akbar Sharif"

Comment: @Arcturus, Yes your assumption is correct

Comment: Is there a reason there is a leading space here btw? `" \f\n\r\t\'\"\\"`

Comment: Can you update your question with the piece of calling JSP code?

Comment: @Arcturus, Yes, the problem is "data" argument can be of any language, like english, thai..etc... when the data is having spaces and if I not include a leading space it is giving "Undetermined String Constant" even if I try to replace escape characters with a character other than space..

Answer (score 3):

I would use regex:

```
String replace(String data) {
    return data.replaceAll("[\f\n\r\t\'\"\\\\]", " ");
}
```

Note the 4 backslashes required to achieve a single literal regex backslash; each pair of backslashes in the String literal makes a single literal backslash in the String, and the resulting pair of backslashes in the String makes a single literal backslash in the regex.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this in notepad because I am not at my machine so I am not 100% that this works but you can try it. What I can tell you is that if you do not want to use regex you should use the string builder to replace characters in a string because strings are immutable in java so your code has to return a new string every time you want to do a replace, which could take a while depending on how many characters have to be replaced in data.

```
 public string replace(String data)
 {
     String strSpecial = "";
     strSpecial = " \f\n\r\t\'\"\\";
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();     

     char charArray[] = strSpecial.toCharArray();
     String strOutData = data;

     for (int i =0;i<data.length();i++)
     {  
         for(int j=0; j < charArray.lenght(); j++)
         {
             if(strOutData.charAt(i) == charArray[j])
                 sb.append(' ');
             else
                 sb.append(strOutData.charAt(i));
         }
     }       
         return(sb.toString());


 }
```

Comment: upvoted for the recommendation to use stringbuilder.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will process characters which are reserved in java like:'\' , it will show no termination of string if we use '\' without any preferred method like "\"" .

Try this:

```
String replace(String data)
    {
        String strSpecial = "";
        strSpecial = " \f\n\r\t\'\"\\";     


        return(strSpecial.replace("\"", " "));

    }
```

Comment: Doesn't matter.. How does this answer his question?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with your method.

Check your calling `JSP` code. If you use this inside a `Javascript` function, check if the parsed `Javascript` code still makes sense.

The easiest way to do this is to just inspect the resulting `HTML`. Perhaps you might find your problem when you examine that.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think it is not working?  I used the following to test and it worked.

```
    string strSpecial = " \f\n\r\t\'\"\\";
    string strtmp2 = strSpecial.Replace('\f', ' ').Replace('\n', ' ').Replace('\r', ' ').Replace('\t', ' ').Replace('\'', ' ').Replace('\"', ' ').Replace('\\', ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and its running fine. This is the code that I ran

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    String strSpecial = "";
    strSpecial = " \f\n\r\t\'\"\\";     

    char charArray[] = strSpecial.toCharArray();
    String strOutData = "S\t\"\'\r\f\n\n\'J";
    for (int i =0;i<charArray.length;i++)
    {  
          strOutData = strOutData.replace(charArray[i], ' ');
}       
    System.out.println(strOutData);
}
```

Can you provide me the input that you are trying with? 
Although, from my side, right way to do this thing is using regular expression